how to temporarily getback to the free video driver ? 20.04
For some reason, I can't use my gtx 770 for some time and need to use my onboard VGA video output: it's a nvidia geforce7xxx nforce630. Only free driver for that. The screen is a VGA only and can go to 1280x1024.
The gtx is unplugged, and onboard video set in bios.
But when I boot 20.04 the resolution is 640x480!
I've checked the video driver tool, screen setting, arandr, nothing, only 640x480.
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau is installed.
Update, upgrade reboot, nothing better.
The only workaround I found is to use recovery boot, then I can use 1024x780, better than nothing, but still not best solution.
So the question is: how can I get back to free video driver ?
And then, what to do when I'll plug my gtx again ?
